# Microsoft.Azure.IpSecurityRestriction not found in Azure PowerShell script

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to run some PowerShell commands and my script is failing on the following line:

```
$ipsr = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.IpSecurityRestriction
```

The error is:

```
Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.IpSecurityRestriction]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded
```

I am trying to run this “inline” in an Azure PowerShell task as part of my deployment pipeline. Is this supported or do I need to first import an assembly?

Comment: Hi, could you let me know whether it solved your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, your reply solved my problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. First, it should be `Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.IpSecurityRestriction`, not `Microsoft.Azure.IpSecurityRestriction`, then make sure you have installed the [`Az.Websites`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Websites/1.1.0) powershell module, just use the command below.

```
Import-Module -Name Az.Websites
New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.IpSecurityRestriction
```

[image]

**Besides**, actually we import the module just for the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites.dll`, so you can also use the command as below, check the path of your `.dll` file.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Websites\1.1.0\Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites.dll'
New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.IpSecurityRestriction
```

[image]